# Code for menu bar at footer

Tags: css, html, footer

I have a slight problem with making the footer work, as the div's aren't going where i want them to go.

Imagine that the image on http://imgur.com/jlaNRhj was at the bottom of the page, at the footer, how would you get the links there? It is going to be spread across the whole of the bottom bit of the page, and i was wondering if you guys could help me out please, as this website that i'm making has to look superb. http://jsfiddle.net/cYMCc/1/ link to website editing.

```
Thanks for looking!
```

Comment: Hi, Firstly I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Secondly [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Could you not just put the footer content in a `div` with the `background-image` set to said image, then finally place the links inside the `div`?

Comment: what would the code look like then? I have tried div's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to a container div and then five divs (for each link) and float them left. Give them a width of 20% for equal width and set a height to keep them consistent. In each div create an anchor tag with classes like up,down,up,down,up. Then css like this: `.down {padding-top:10px;}` for example. Good luck and let me know how it goes once you've got that structure setup.

Comment: Thank you so much mate! Will tell you how it going in a minute